# CSV displaying wrong in mac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, macos, csv

I am working on a asp.net mvc 4 project that will be used by different peoples around the world. 
I have an option that will download all the registered users of the project in csv format. I am creating the csv by my self without an external class and for separating the values i use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator` 
to get the current culture list separator but for some reason this doesn't work on macs and all the result display in one column(it works fine on windows).
I have read that in macs the list separator is ";" and not "," but i don't know how to manage in code to detect it automatically. I want something that will work with all the programs capable of displaying csv not only excel.
Does somebody know how i can do this?

Comment: ListSeparator is using the value set on the server, if it does not match what Mac Excel expects it wont work. See [How to get Excel to interpret the comma as a default delimiter in CSV files?](http://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files)

Comment: Yes, but i want a solution to work in all the programs. It seems that adding "sep=," in the beagining of the csv file works only in excel.